# Which is the more appropriate word to use "stupidity" or "idiocy" in a medical context

Tags: word-choice

I have encountered this problem while i was trying to translate a medical text to English. The text was about the newly discovered virus that can cause mental and cognitive problems

Comment: Unless it's a historical medical text, don't use either of those.

Comment: The terminology changes roughly every 30 years, when the old term "wears out".  "Idiot" used to be a technical term, then "mental retardation", then something else.  It may be safest to stick to a non-specific phrase such as "causes cognitive problems".

Answer (score 3):

[Idiocy](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/idiocy) is an obsolete term for: (from TFD)

> severe **[mental retardation](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/mental+retardation)**  in medical context.
>
> - Mental retardation is a developmental disability that first appears in children under the age of 18. It is defined as an intellectual functioning level (as measured by standard tests for intelligence quotient) that is well below average and significant limitations in daily living skills (adaptive functioning).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mental%20retardation%2Cidiocy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmental%20retardation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiocy%3B%2Cc0): idiocy vs mental retardation.

Resources:

> - Organizations
>     American Association on Mental Retardation (AAMR). 444 North Capitol St., NW, Suite 846, Washington, D.C. 20001-1512. (800) 424-3688. http://www.aamr.org.

Comment: However, this is an `obsolete` term.

Comment: Idiocy - based on your definition - probably wouldn't really fit a situation where mental and cognitive problems are brought on by a virus.

Comment: Well, whatever the reason, OP is asking for a way to define idiocy in a medical context and I think 'mental retardation' is appropriate.

Comment: "Idiocy" is an extremely anachronistic word for cognitive impairment. They stopped using that word probably 100 years ago. Then it switched to "mental retardation", which is now more-or-less anachronistic as well, and now they are specific and call out *what* *kind* of mental impairment we're talking about, generally along one of several axes in the DSM:  

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnostic_and_Statistical_Manual_of_Mental_Disorders

The closest to "mental retardation" in the DSM is probably "Intellectual Dev. Disorder", but depending on the situation something more specific may apply.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably avoid both in a medical context. I'd probably use something along the lines of

> mental <strike>handicap</strike> impairment (Even my example is becoming insulting, see below)

or

> cognitive difficulties

There are lots of words for disabled people that started as medical terms, but have since turned into insults so please be careful which you do pick. [Spastic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spastic) is one example that comes to mind. It originally meant somebody with cerebral palsy, but is now used as a (quite offensive) general insult.

Comment: Even "handicap" is avoided these days.  I'd probably use "mental impairment".

Comment: *Stupid* is another example: it meant originally one who was *stupefied*, in a *stupor*. Now it is no longer a medical condition but a universal human condition. :)

Answer (score 2):

In medical jargon we use "**intellectual disability**" (formerly known as "mental retardation")

> Intellectual disability (ID) is a neurodevelopmental disorder characterized by deficits in intellectual and adaptive functioning that present before 18 years of age.
>
> Intellectual disability (ID) is a state of functioning that begins in childhood and is characterized by limitations in intelligence and adaptive skills.

These definitions are from "www.uptodate.com", not an open site.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_disability) we have the following:

> Intellectual disability (ID), also called intellectual development disorder (IDD) and formerly known as mental retardation (MR), is a neurodevelopmental disorder characterized by impaired intellectual and adaptive functioning which is defined by an IQ score below 70 as well as a delay in general daily living skills. Other common symptoms include speech delays and lack of social functioning.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the damage that a virus does/can cause, I would use the term "cognitive impairment".  Depending upon the severity, possibly "serious cognitive impairment".

This is not the same as being "stupid", which most commonly refers to not thinking instead of the inability to think well these days, likewise for idiocy.  If they ever had a medical meaning, that meaning has been almost completely supplanted by the "doh, I forgot to..." or "what kind of...forgets to set the emergency brake while parking on a hill?" usage.

Answer (score 0):

Physicians are generally trained to be very careful when addressing these types of issues.  People in general are very sensitive about how and what they are called.  Some of the more progressive physicians try to avoid labeling people at all.  However, it is not very realistic when discussing conditions at conferences or with another colleague not to have some poignant and meaningful terminology to use as a reference. Many long hours are spent by doctors, researchers, and editors to determine the best words to describe an observation or characteristic.  It will never be perfect but it has vastly improved over the years.  One always should remember that we are all human beings and we should always do our best to get along with each other.  Any human can be subjected to any human condition so it's important to make reasonable effort to treat people fairly and develop caring and understanding.  The best way we can change the world is by changing ourselves.

Comment: Although "Don't label people" is a valid opinion to hold, that's not an option when translating an existing work which does that.